# Why is the twitter API throwing this error?

Tags: java, twitter

The error message suggests that my "request was denied due to update limits". But this account hasn't tweeted anythin in the last 24 hours and it also says `retryAfter=-1`. I tried it with the current stable and the snapshot build of twitter4j but it didn't help. Does someone know what is wrong?

```
403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
message - Application cannot perform write actions. Contact Twitter Platform Operations through https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform
code - 261

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=2fc5b7cb or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0f38fea7
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[2fc5b7cb-0f38fea7], statusCode=403, message=Application cannot perform write actions. Contact Twitter Platform Operations through https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform, code=261, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.5-SNAPSHOT(build: bbbd24f6c492677f65d3956ed6b74a2ae75d5bc3)}
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:86)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.post(TwitterImpl.java:1812)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.updateStatus(TwitterImpl.java:218)
```

Comment: So did you lookup the code `261` and read the discussion URLs shown in the message?

Comment: I did. The links don't work at all, the code just means that my update limits ran out. But that cannot be the case

Comment: The code listing suggests you have been suspended and need to appeal the suspension. See [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes) and scroll down to error code 261.

Comment: Ok, that is funny. I will contact them to sort this out. Thank you!

Comment: Only five minutes after my request twitter unblocked my application. Nice!

Comment: Whatever you did to get suspended, try not to do it again :-).  *".... my update limits ran out.  But that cannot be the case."* - Yes, well perhaps you should think again about that.  'Cos if you get suspended again, it may take *longer* to get unsuspended ...

Comment: Yes, this actually really bothers me but I seriously can't think of a reason to suspend me. Can you maybe look at @ subcounterINT and @ aboerfolgeDE and tell me why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code 261 means the API-token was suspended. It takes only 10 minutes to appeal the suspension and get everything up and running again.

Answer (score 2):

If the suspension isn't lifted (I appealed several times but it didn't), you could create a new standalone app (in the overview) and replace the consumer and access tokens with the new ones. It worked for me.

Comment: I now have 2 appeals for a legit pro-science reply bots that got code 261. So your answer is helpful