# Why can't I delete multiple tweets with this code? Python tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am trying to use this code to delete 550 tweets from my account, as I want to use it as my personal account again without the tweets from my bots:

```
import tweepy
import json

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("consumer_key", "consumer_secret")

auth.set_access_token("access_token", "access_token_secret")

api = tweepy.API(auth)

screen_name = "YOUR_TWITTER_HANDLE"

timelines = api.user_timeline(screen_name, count = 550, include_rts = False)

for status in timelines:
    tweetid = status._json
    api.destroy_status(tweetid)
```

But every time I run it, I get this error:

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'Application cannot perform write actions. Contact Twitter Platform Operations through https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform', 'code': 261}]
```

When I print `tweetid`, it is successfully grabbing all my tweets. I can also tweet normally using `api.update_status`, so why is this not working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your specific case looks like a permission issue. However, the code would still fail even if you have the appropriate permissions. `tweet_id` is a dictionary where one of the keys contains the id, so the correct code would be `tweetid['id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your API key has been restricted (this can happen if you try to perform too many automated actions, see  the automation rules https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation). You will need to have the app restored via https://help.twitter.com/forms/automation

Comment: But when I try to submit a ticket (in the account in question) it says 'Your account is neither suspended nor locked' Am I looking to submit a ticket in the wrong area?

Comment: Oh and  https://help.twitter.com/forms/automation seems to just redirect back to /forms

Comment: OK. I may have made a mistake then. To keep this on topic for Stack, you might want to come to the Twitter specific developer forums. If you can share your app ID (not the consumer key etc) we might be able to look into it. I'm still fairly convinced this is an app overuse issue.

Comment: Ok I will open a new topic on that forum sometime today.

Answer (score 1):

seems like you have made to many requests to the twitter api - from my little reasearch the error code 261 means the token was suspended. Check this links:

[Why is the twitter API throwing this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826934/why-is-the-twitter-api-throwing-this-error)

https://blog.cotten.io/common-twitter-error-codes-6b324396042e

Comment: Then how come I can still `update_status` and everything else? It just seems to be deleting tweets that doesn't work